# Flutter UI design

Tags: java, android, flutter

He investigado un poco pero aun me hes confuso el tema Flutter... Quisiera que alguien me explicara en que consiste exactamente Flutter y como puede ser utilizado en aplicaciones donde ya tenga desarrollada Activities y quiera llamar a un nuevo activity con Flutter por ejemplo o viceversa tener un activity con Flutter y llamar a una activity sin el.. Es eso posible??

Por ejemplo

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
          home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
      ),
    body: Center(
      child: Text('Hello World'),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Y desde ahi llamar a un Activity por ejemplo

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Quisiera que alguien me explicara en que consiste exactamente Flutter

Flutter es un SDK que permite crear aplicaciones compiladas de forma nativa para Android, IOS, Web y escritorio utilizando widgets (personalmente me gusta ver a los widgets como bloques de lego).

> como puede ser utilizado en aplicaciones donde ya tenga desarrollada
>   Activities

Según entiendo, lo que buscas es agregar Flutter a una aplicación ya existente escrita en lenguaje nativo en este caso Java, y si... es posible. La idea esta en agregar flutter como una librería(modulo) a tu actual proyecto. Además de la [documentación oficial](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps#use-the-flutter-module-from-your-java-code), este [articulo](https://blog.codemagic.io/flutter-module-android-yaml/) te puede ayudar mucho.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias x la ayuda creo que con eso me basta

Answer (score 1):

Flutter funciona ligeramente diferente a Android, primero que todo, tienes 2 clases diferentes para crear un activity (o widget "cualquier cosa que se crea es un widget").

Existen los **Stateless Widgets**, los que son vistas estáticas que no pueden ser modificadas por medio de la interacción de un usuario, es decir, por ejemplo tenemos un campo de texto, pero no vas a poder obtener los valores de ese campo de texto.

Luego están los **Stateful Widgets**, los que permiten realizar modificaciones al usuario, tanto en animaciones como en obtención de datos. Los Stateful Widgets son los únicos que tienen los métodos @initState, @dispose, que simulan los @onCreate y @onDestroy en desarrollo nativo.

Generalmente se utilizan los Stateless Widgets para los activities, porque exigen menos rendimiento al dispositivo que los Stateful, aunque hay formas de modificar la interacción de usuario por medio de algunos (no todos) **Manejadores de Estado**, los cuales pueden ser SetState, Provider, Cubit, BloC, entre otros. Por defecto Flutter te entrega uno llamado SetState, y es necesario utilizar Stateful Widgets para que funcione.